# Error when update data from DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a problem here, I have a query to the database, where I choose only one table, loads it into the dataSet and fill the DataGridView.

```
comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from measurement where me_user=@id order by me_date DESC", conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.uId);
daPomiar = new SqlDataAdapter();
daPomiar.SelectCommand = comm;
daPomiar.Fill(dsPomiar, "Pomiary");
dataGridView2.DataSource = dsPomiar;
dataGridView2.DataMember = "Pomiary";
```

Adds to this

```
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daPomiar);
```

However, when I try to update the data using BindingNavigotor:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daPomiar);
    daPomiar.Update(dsPomiar, "Pomiary");
}
```

then sometimes it works and sometimes it gives me an error:

> Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

My question is, why it happens. I am working on one table, so I can use SqlCommandBuilder (I think). Well, the error is not regular - sometimes error appears and sometimes it works - the data is updated in the table.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query tells me that you are selecting data from the `measurement` table. I believe you are trying to update to the `Pomiary` table. Although you are providing a DataMember and such, I believe the best practice is to keep your DataMember and table names all the same.

Also, make sure your connection is open, I don't see anything on that, might be left out.

```
string tableName = "measurement";
comm = new SqlCommand("Select * from measurement where me_user=@id order by me_date DESC", conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.uId); //not sure what this does
daPomiar = new SqlDataAdapter(comm, tableName);
daPomiar.Fill(dsPomiar, tableName);
dataGridView2.DataSource = dsPomiar;
```

toolstrip:

```
private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(daPomiar);
    daPomiar.Update(dsPomiar, tablename);
}
```